# Tokenizing string and checking for digit

Tags: php

So I'm really fresh to PHP – like this is my first dive into it at all!

What I'm doing is attempting to take a string that is passed in from a form and parse it by a delimiter. I'm currently using a '-' for the delimiter. If the item I'm looking for has been entered there will be an integer value for one of the items.

Basically a valid string I'm looking for will be in the form:

> -QUANTITY-SKU-TITLE-PRICE

The SKU, Title, and Price are guaranteed to be filled in, the Quantity, however, is not.
So I could receive a string in the format

> -20-SKU: 5563-Product A-Price: $19.95

or alternatively

> --SKU: 5563-Product A-Price: $19.95

if the particular product was not acutally ordered (i.e. no quantity actually ordered).
These strings are also passed in concatenated, so I'm attempting to tokenize use the '-' as my delimeter, and if a digit is encountered (which only the QUANTITY portion of the string should match) I'm returning a string containg the data needed.

The problem is `ctype_digit` is never evaluating to true?

```
public function display_entry_cp ($data)
{
    $process_product = explode("-", $data);
    $return_array = "Products ordered:\n";
    //print_r($process_product);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($process_product); ++$i) {
        // echo($process_product[$i] . "<br/>");
        if($process_product[$i] != '' && ctype_digit($process_product[$i])){
            echo("Element is digit!");
            // look for the first int seen, that is our quantity, next is SKU, Title then Price
            $ordered_product = 'Quantity: ' . $process_product[$i] . ' ' . $process_product[++$i] . ' ' . $process_product[++$i] . ' ' . $process_product[++$i];
            $return_array = $ordered_product;
        }
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

When echoing the `$process_product[$i]` I'm seeing what I would expect, just can't figure out how to only insert an item if a QUANTITY has been entered?

Example if print out looks like:

```
133 
SKU: 1101 
Description: Product A
Price: $8.95 

SKU: 1200 
Description: Product B
Price: $9.50 

SKU: 1105 
Description: Product C
Price: $17.95 
133 
SKU: 910 
Description: Product D
Price: $19.95
```

In this example the string returned would look like:

> -133-SKU: 1101-Description: Product A: $8.95--SKU: 1200-Description: Product B-Price: $9.50--SKU: 1105-Description: Product C-Price: $17.95-133-SKU: 910-Description: Product D: $19.95

In this example, I would only want to return the first item, and the last.

Comment: where is this data coming from? if it's in separate pieces elsewhere, then it should be KEPT separate and not slapped into an arbitrary strings. consider what'd happen if the product name naturally contains a `-`.

Comment: Try `list($qty, $sku, $descr, $price) = explode("-", $data);` in addition to `if (!$qty) { // error here }`

Comment: @Marc B you make a good point. I should probably being using a more "unique" delimiter.

Comment: @ccKep, thanks for the suggestion! I will try this and see if I have luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've come up with a solution - as I'm no expert I would like to know if this is considered "better" than my method above?

```
public function display_entry_cp ($data)
{

    /*
    *   Precondition: String comes in the format:
    *   "SKU/DESCR/PRICE/QTY,SKU/DESCR/PRICE/,SKU/DESCR/PRICE/QTY," ...etc
    *   QTY may or may not be an empty string - this is our indicator that item was ordered
    */ 

    // First get all the products into single lines we can work with
    $process_product = explode(",", $data);
    // String to hold our return value
    $return_str = "Products ordered:";
    // Loop through and process the extracted strings
    foreach($process_product as $value) {
        // Testing
        //echo($value . "<br/>");
        try{
            // Split the string by the "/" delimiter
            $explode = explode("/", $value);
            // Count should always be 4, even if no QTY entered, it will contain " "
            if(count($explode) == 4){
                list($sku, $descr, $price, $qty) = explode("/", $value);
                // Checking if there really is a QTY
                if (trim($qty) !== "") {
                    //echo(" SKU: " . $sku . " Description: " . $descr . " Price: $" . $price . " Qty: " . $qty . "<br/>");
                    $ordered_product = (" SKU: " . $sku . " Description: " . $descr . " Price: $" . $price . " Qty: " . $qty);
                    //echo($ordered_product);
                    $return_str .= $ordered_product;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage()); 
            return;
        } // end try/catch
    }// end foreach

// Final check to see if return_str is what we expect
//echo($return_str);
return $return_str;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, the string will now come in the format:

> "SKU/DESCR/PRICE/QTY,SKU/DESCR/PRICE/,SKU/DESCR/PRICE/QTY," ...etc

The QTY may, or may not, be empty. In either case, it will contain a preceding space (" ") character.
Now I can delimit by a comma (",") first to get all of the products into a string of their own. From there, I can further split the string apart into its individual components. This also allowed me the ability to use a "foreach()" loop as apposed to a "for()" loop.

Please let me know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I took a longer look at this. The data you provide as a sample doesn't match the spec - that is, there should be two adjacent hyphens at the start of a record with no quantity but your data has only one. Your code isn't handling that so your subsequent tokens aren't what it's expecting so your condition fails.

If you add in the missing hyphens this code works, sort of.

There is a different problem. There's a different problem where you're assembling the `$order_product` string. You're incrementing the loop index variable on each term. That's sort of OK (but really bad practice since it'll confuse someone later), except that where you have a short record the index is incremented beyond the number of elements in the array.

There is a reason why programmers use field *and record* delimiters: it makes it possible to handle this sort of discrepancy reliably. There is already a good format for this: CSV is well understood and reliable.

But, you say this data is coming from a form. If so it must be appearing in a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable somewhere. Somehow, presumably, you've mashed the data into this proprietary format to run this routine on it. I have to ask: why?

This is a classic *xy* problem. You've asked about one thing, but you really should be asking about something else. In this case, I'd guess, form handling in PHP

Comment: you're correct on the missing hyphens! I've made the adjustments in the original post. That was a mistake on my part. I know incrementing the count is bad, I cringed when I did that. At this point I'm simply trying to get it to work, and then I can work on optimizing it to make it more robust.

Comment: I will also look into the CSV format. I hadn't thought of using that as a blueprint. And yes, the data does come in from $_POST, but this is a class that inherits from the parent class. I don't have access to the "original" data. It just grabs all the fields and passes them on. I have access to the $data field, that's it.

Comment: Also, just an FWIW, all of the data has already been stored for safe keeping, I'm just trying to manipulate the string for display purposes.